# How can I do a padding between my highest x-value and the plot's right gap in Highcharts?

Tags: line, padding, highcharts

I need to delete the margins between my lines and plot gap. [image: the problem that I need to resolve] 
I decided to use the startOnTick and endOnTick property but in this case line's points in the gap are not seen or seen only part of them.[image: what I found - another problem]

Please, help if you know how, of course)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `maxPadding` and `minPadding` within chart options provided to the constructor.

Or you can use `setExtremes(min, max)` after instantiate the chart for dynamic values.

```
var myChart = new Highchart.chart(options),
extremes = myChart.xAxis[0].getExtremes(),
minPadding = 20,
maxPadding = 20;
myChart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.dataMin - minPadding, extremes.dataMax + maxPadding);
```